# PhP validation issue

Tags: php, validation

I'm trying to validate the information my users enter in my registration form to ensure that it is in the correct format. The code works without the if statements, so the link to the database and the insertion is working...

This is my code:

```
<?php

include 'link.php';

$errors = 0;

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$salt = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 0, 22);
$hash = sha1($salt . $password);

if(0 === preg_match("/.+@.+\..+/", $_POST['email'])) {
    $errors++;
    echo '<script>alert("Please enter a valid email.");</script>';
}

if(0 === preg_match("/.{6,}/", $_POST['password'])) {
    $errors++;
    echo '<script>alert("Please enter a valid password.");</script>';
}

if(0 === count($errors)) {

$sql = "INSERT INTO labb2 (email, password, salt) VALUES ('$email', '$hash', '$salt')";
$result = $link->query($sql);

echo '<script>alert("Account successfully created");</script>';
header("refresh:0; url=register.php");

}

else {

    echo '<script>alert("Account not created.");</script>';
    header("refresh:0; url=register.php");

}


?>
```

The code never reaches my last if-statement and so a user is never entered into the database even though the information entered is in the correct format.

Comment: Allow users to use the [passwords / phrases](https://xkcd.com/936/) they desire.

[Don't limit passwords.](http://jayblanchard.net/security_fail_passwords.html)

Comment: You really shouldn't use your own salts on password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79668/login-with-password-hash) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: `count` returns the amount of variables, Since `$error` is a variable, it will *always* return *true*. Try `$errors = 0; var_dump(count($errors));`. It will say 1. You need to check `if ($errors==0)`. By the way you are not checking strict booleans, so why the `===` ?

Comment: In addition to the above advice: You probably shouldn't create scripts directly from the php file either, you'd be better writing separate script files and setting EventHandlers which activate the scripts. 1) It makes your code look cleaner and 2) you're less likely to run into syntax errors or have to escape certain characters.